# Why "number input" spin buttons generate "change" event on mouseout in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a default "input type=number" element.
In Chrome browser when I set a value and then hover over the spin buttons it generates "change" event on mouseout.
https://www.screencast.com/t/9LlIg9g9

Steps to replicate:

1. Set a value of input
2. Mouseover spin buttons
3. Mouseout spin buttons

Result: you'll see an alert with the value.

Why is this happening?

And how can I prevent generating "change" in that case (or how can I distinguish it)? I want to get "change" event in all other default cases.

```js
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('change', function(e){
 alert(this.value)
})
```

```html
<input id="a" type="number"/>
```

Comment: Checking from chrome here, works fine for me. But anyway, maybe you can just check the value explicitly? Like `if (oldval !== this.value)`?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior.

Comment: @StepanShilin there always be a new value, because I do change it. Did you change the value before mouseenter/mouseleave the buttons in your testing? Updated post with "steps to replicate".

Comment: Looks like this may have been a regression caused by fixing another bug. See [this comment in the Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155747#c17) where they note the occurrence of it. I don't see any further comments after 18 that mention it however. Might have been missed. I encourage you to submit an issue for this.